# jQuery Pausing Default Effect for a class

Tags: jquery

So christening myself with my first post (on stackoverflow)...

1) I'm trying to create a pause of effect with opacity 1 on hover of the effect for a star twinkle effect, but only affect the exact element hovering on (and not the entire class) since there will be multiple links on the page.

2) I don't know if I should use preventDefault() on mouseenter or something like on mouseenter use .stop() then mouseleave use .animate()

3) Can the following code can be shortened to be more efficient.

I created the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mikemccarson/ywumubtd/

Here is the jQuery found in the jsfiddle:

```
var slowTwinkle = $('.twinkleStarText');


        $('#starUv').delay(50);
        $('#starWorm').delay(500);
        $('#starBlack').delay(1550);
        $('#starNeb').delay(3340);
        $('#starRegister').delay(2350);

function twinkleSlow() {
            slowTwinkle.animate({ opacity: '+=1' }, 500);
            slowTwinkle.animate({ opacity: '=1' }, 700);
            slowTwinkle.animate({ opacity: '-=0.5' }, 500, twinkleSlow);
        }

    twinkleSlow();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only about hovering, a simple css rule could suffice:

```
.homePageLinks:hover{
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

(Adding !important makes sure your javascript will not get in your way.)
(Not sure what you mean by a "star twinkle effect", though.)

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you so much.